# Why my object seems to be created two times?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

so i am currently learning some class today and i got confuse on how to display the functions

```
dateType::dateType()
{
    cout<<"Object Created\n";
}

void dateType::setDate()
{
    cout<<"Enter Month: ";
    cin>>month;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Date: ";
    cin>>day;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Year: ";
    cin>>year;
    cout<<endl;
}

.....
//other function declaration to access the private 
.....

void dateType:: printdate()
{
    cout<<"Month: "<<month<<endl;
    cout<<"Date: "<<day<<endl;
    cout<<"Year: "<<year<<endl;
    cout<<"Leap Year: \n"<<endl;
}

dateType::~dateType()
{
    cout<<"Object Deleted";
}

int main()
{
    dateType().setDate(); 
    dateType().printdate();

    return 0;
}
```

now when i run the program it works fine but the problem is the constructor and destruct  display two times.

[Photo of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpL2c.jpg)

[Full code](http://ideone.com/dJ3cqO)

Comment: full code is not available.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/dJ3cqO)

Comment: Ask yourself what the expression `dateType()` actually does in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the object you created is destroyed after setDate() method is called because there is no identifier to it in main. You just created it, called a method and then it's over.
You did:

`dateType().setDate()`;

so dataType object is created when you do dateType(). But after its setDate() method is called, it's destroyed because you have not saved it anywhere.

Try doing:

```
dateType p;
p.setDate();
```

it won't get destroyed this time.

Comment: Hey can you help me out , why it double it's output , if i enter 2,4,6,9,11.
the 31 will show up.. [double display](http://imgur.com/a/qeVSZ)

Comment: i already declared the leapyear so no need for me to  put them in.

Comment: Remove condition from else, if "if" and " else if" doesn't run, else will automatically run. We don't have any condition in else. You can see this video tutorial for understanding how this works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbcdzXEN5kQ

Comment: oohh my bad wasn't paying attend to my code thank you again